# GNU parallel \bin\bash command not found

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'm following this tutorial here [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/dimaio/files/rosetta_density_tutorial_may17.pdf), I installed GNU parallel and tested it using the ping command as per the read me [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README).

Trying:

```
parallel –j8 ./ A_asymm_refine.sh {} ::: {1..8}
```

Gives:

```
[user@machine Documents]$ parallel –j8 ./ A_asymm_refine.sh {} ::: {1..8}
Academic tradition requires you to cite works you base your article on.
If you use programs that use GNU Parallel to process data for an article in a
scientific publication, please cite:

  O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool,
  ;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.

This helps funding further development; AND IT WON'T COST YOU A CENT.
If you pay 10000 EUR you should feel free to use GNU Parallel without citing.

To silence this citation notice: run 'parallel --citation'.

/usr/bin/bash: $'\342\200\223j8': command not found
/usr/bin/bash: $'\342\200\223j8': command not found
/usr/bin/bash: $'\342\200\223j8': command not found
/usr/bin/bash: $'\342\200\223j8': command not found
/usr/bin/bash: $'\342\200\223j8': command not found
/usr/bin/bash: $'\342\200\223j8': command not found
/usr/bin/bash: $'\342\200\223j8': command not found
/usr/bin/bash: $'\342\200\223j8': command not found
```

How can I troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: You used an 'en-dash' character (U+2013) instead of a hyphen (U+002D = ASCII 0x2D) on the option. Perhaps you cut&paste this command from a Microsoft-mangled document or a poorly-coded website. Instead type it on the keyboard and **use the normal hyphen key**.

Comment: Thanks. I know get """"/usr/bin/bash: ./: Is a directory""" a bunch of times.

Comment: Never mind, there was an extra white space before the foward slash.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, sorry for the off-topic question, but what does {} ::: {1..8} do exactly?

Comment: `{}` is replaced on each execution with an input value and `::: values` specifies the input values on the commandline -- see [parallel manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Reading-arguments-from-command-line) `{1..8}` is expanded by the shell to the values 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -- see [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
parallel -j8 ./A_asymm_refine.sh {} ::: {1..8}
```